# Determining Boiling Point and Melting Point by Graph

Tags: thermodynamics, phase, entropy

This is the plot of $\Delta G^{^\circ}$ vs $T$ for $\ce{Pb-> PbO}$

[image: Delta Gibbs free energy vs temperature for lead compounds]

I understand that the points where there is a sudden change in the slope of the graph, there is a phase change but exactly what are the reactions going at all the four points shown and also how can we justify whether it is a point of melting or boiling and what further can we conclude from this graph about entropy? Specifically, I am more concerned about the main reaction and what are the individual reactions at every point: $$\ce{Pb(s) + \frac{1}{2}O_2(g) -> PbO(s)}$$

Comment: Have you looked up the melting and boiling points ?

Comment: What is the context and *origin* of the graph shown?  Cite the source to add detail to your question, please.  For the points shown, there may be phase transitions solid -> solid, solid -> liquid ($\approx \pu{328 ^\circ{}C}$), liquid -> gaseous ($\approx \pu{1744 ^\circ{}C}$), the later two one may look up, e.g., in Wikipedia's properties box about the element. Yet that is not all yet, as there *may* be indeed onsets of oxidation reactions.  Note, lead and oxygen may e.g., yield $\ce{PbO}$, or $\ce{PbO2}$, or *mixed* oxides (like minium, formally Pb II and Pb IV are present simultaneously).

Comment: What do you report in ordinate ? Is it a Gibbs energy of formation ? Of which product ? Why do the points seem equidistant on the graph ?

Comment: @Buttonwood, Yes, but specifically only about PbO

Comment: @Maurice, gibbs energy of formation of PbO

Comment: @Community Independent of Maurice' good note about the points' distance along *T* (about $\approx \pu{200 K}$ above $\pu{1535 ^\circ{}C}$ are anticipated as considerably shorter than the $\approx \pu{650 K}$ above $\pu{888 ^\circ{}C}$), there is too few information here.  Is it accidental coincidence, or intent (if so, why?) that $\ce{PbO}$'s melting point ($\pu{888 ^\circ{}C}$) and boiling point ($\pu{1477 ^\circ{}C}$) apparently equally are in this diagram of (still) unquoted origin? How (if so) did you compute it?

Comment: PbO exists under two crystallographic systems : tetragonal and rhombic. The point at $327$°C is probably the transition between these two forms. $888$°C is the melting point, and $1749$°C the boiling point. The problem is how to explain the point at $1535$°C in the liquid state, which is accompanied by an increase in stability  ...

Comment: At least two points is clear: $\pu{327 ^\circ C}$ is the melting point of $\ce{Pb}$ and $\pu{888 ^\circ C}$ is the melting point of $\ce{PbO}$.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne, won't the 888 C point be boiling point of Pb? Maybe we can also lookout for the equation of gibbs free energy and entropy

Comment: Good point in a sense of which I didn't think about that. It clears the last break: Boiling point of $\ce{Pb}$ is $\pu{1749 ^\circ C}$. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lead(II)_oxide), melting point of $\ce{PbO}$ is $\pu{888^\circ C}$ and its boiling point is $\pu{1477 ^\circ C}$. That is the only odd number in your graph.